# Why does pandas read_csv have unicode error when encoding utf-8 is specified?

Tags: python, pandas

When executing the following Python 3.6 code in Jupyter 5.000 notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
file = "C:\users\frogf\MSDS7333\data\HIGGS.csv"
data=pd.read_csv(file,nrows=N,header=None,encoding = "utf-8")
```

it gives the error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-5-204f62a7e8b4>", line 2
    file = "C:\users\frogf\MSDS7333\data\HIGGS.csv"
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Comment: Probably because the file is not actually valid UTF-8 - what exactly is the content in that line?

Comment: You need to escape the back slashes or pass a raw string: `file = r"C:\users\frogf\MSDS7333\data\HIGGS.csv"` `'\u'` is a unicode escape sequence, if this is the error I'm voting to close as it's a typo

Comment: its a large dataset from Keras 2.6 GB download.

Comment: @EdChum looks exactly what is to me... positions 2 and 3 are `\u` and it's not a raw string...

Comment: adding escape chars worked.   sorry to ask dumb question, please close it.

Answer (score 1):

open the file as raw string. Try:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\frogf\MSDS7333\data\HIGGS.csv",nrows=10,header=None,encoding = "utf-8")
```